# loading all images with different names from drive in python

Tags: python, image, file, opencv

Multiple images are stored in my google drive folder. All images have different names. I want to load them all for my deep learning project. All loaded images should be of type numpy array. What can I do? 
Here is the code that I have implemented

```
import cv2
loc="" #My drive directory location
```

I have successfully loaded one images using

```
img=cv2.imread(str(loc)+"image_name.png",1)
```

I am stuck here, because names of all images are different

Comment: So, you want to use them locally or on Google Colab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all image names using `os.listdir('you image folder path')`. You can do something like this:

```
import os,cv2
for image_path in os.listdir('image folder path'):
      cv2.imread(base_path + image_path,1)
```